I can't figure out to build a flattened structure for nested for_each when the inner map is optional and null
I'm trying to build this flattened structure:
locals {
  containers = flatten([
    for storage_key, st in var.Storage : [
      for cont_key, cont in st.containers : {
        storage_key  = storage_key,
        storage_name = st.name,
        cont_name    = cont_key,
        access_type  = cont.container_access_type
      }
    ]
  ])
}

but my problem is that the variable specs allow the container to map to be null:
variable "Storage" {
  type = map(object({
    name                     = string
    containers = optional(map(object({
      container_access_type = string
    })))
  }))
}
with these default values:
Storage = {
  stor1 = {
    name                      = "accntpriv"
    containers = {
      mgmt-media = {
        container_access_type = "private"
      }
      mgmt-comm = {
        container_access_type = "private"
      }
      mgmt-static = {
        container_access_type = "blob"
      }
    }
  }
}

I want to add containers to existing storage accounts identified by the storage name.
Thanks for helping!
Wolfgang

This works, thanks for your patience
locals {
  containers = flatten([
    for storage_key, st in var.Storage : [
      for cont_key, cont in coalesce(st.containers, {}) : 
        {
          storage_key  = storage_key,
          storage_name = st.name,
          cont_name    = cont_key,
          access_type  = cont.container_access_type
        }
    ]
  ])
}


One option is to use the coalesce function with your attribute value as the first argument and and tomap({}) (an empty map) as the second argument, which will then return the value of the first argument that isn't null.
However, if your module never needs to distinguish between containers = {} and the attribute not being set at all then you can ask Terraform to do that for you automatically when preparing the input variable value, by declaring a different default value for the optional attribute:
variable "Storage" {
  type = map(object({
    name                     = string
    containers = optional(
      map(object({
        container_access_type = string
      })),
      {},
    )
  }))
}

The second argument to optional(...) specifies a value Terraform should use instead whenever this attribute would be null. In the above example I set this to {}, which Terraform will then convert into an empty map of your declared object type.
Once you've done this you can assume that the containers attribute of these objects will never be null, and will therefore always be a valid map of your given object type. The map might be empty, but it will never be null.
